# Why does Ettercap scan the wrong hosts?

Tags: sniffing, vmware

**Details:**

I'm running three virtual machines on VMware Workstation:

- Virtual Machine 1: Windows 7. Using static ip: 10.1.1.1
- Virtual Machine 2: Windows server 2008. Using static ip 10.1.1.2
- Virtual Machine 3: Kali Linux. Using static ip 10.1.1.3

They are connected to eachother via a host-only network on VMNet1.

I want to sniff packets going between the two windows machines using Kali Linux's Ettercap.

But when I scan for hosts on the eth0 interface (10.1.1.3) in Ettercap I get the following ip addresses:
[image]

Comment: Isn't the VSwitch a level 2 switch?

Comment: I'd want to confirm your network config

Comment: How are you launching the scan?

Comment: I just go to Hosts > Scan for hosts

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your eth0 connection on your Kali VM has its network adapter setup incorrectly and is actually using your host machine's network (192.168.128.*).

You need to make sure that your VMs are actually using the host-only network.

On your VMs, run ifconfig and check that eth0 is actually on your 10.1.1.* subnet. If it's not, you'll need to double check the eth0 connection setting within your VMs, and that the VMWare network settings for the VMs are correct.

Comment: ifconfig on Kali Linux outputs: "inet 10.1.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.1.255"

Comment: Are you sure there is just one virtual adapter?

Comment: Yes. All the machines are connected to the same VMnet1 adapter.

Comment: And can you ping those two machines?

Comment: I ment just eth0 on Kali linux. ifconfig -a

Comment: Yes I can ping both machines.

Comment: ifconfig -a. Same result.

Comment: can you also ping those two discovered hosts? what about route <s>print</s>? Sorry, just route. print is for windows

Comment: It says "Network unreachable". Maybe it's just a bug. I'll restart the whole VMware and see if it persists.

Comment: Oh wait, crap. I pinged the wrong ip. Yes I can ping 192.168.128.1 fine.

Comment: Here's a strange thing though: If I ping 10.1.1.1 I get a duplicate packet (DUP!) for each packet sent. It arrives several milliseconds after the original packet.

Comment: You want to ping devices on the 10.1.1.* network from Kali VM to other VMs.  Pinging the 192.168.128.1 tells you that eth0 is not using the host only adapter.

Comment: @SecretSasquatch I did ping 10.1.1.1. It gives a duplicate packet for each packet. So why would eth0 not be using the host-only adapter?

Comment: Not sure about the 'duplicate packets' you are mentioning.  You might want to triple-check your Kali VM's Network Manager configuration and make sure that the eth0 connection is setup on the right subnet and static IP, also make sure that when you run ettercap it's using eth0...  Other than that I'm, out of ideas for now =)

Comment: Hm. I go to VM>Settings>Network Adapter and it says it's using VMnet1

Comment: Check the network settings within the Kali VM as well...I think that is where your problem is.

Comment: Also in the bottom-right corner that two-screen icon thing says I'm on the VMnet1 adapter.

Comment: Wow! I went to Wired settings in Kali and it says the ipv4 address is 192.168.128.156 . What do I do?

Comment: Wait. I noticed something. I just set the ip again through "ifconfig eth0 10.1.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0" and the ip in wired settings changed to 10.1.1.3. It looks like for some reason the Kali Linux machine defaults back to the 192.168.128.156 ip on its own.

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure.  Sounds like you need may need to read up a bit more on configuring the host-only network.  Something is astray in your setup...